# Why does membership IsApproved set itself to false?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-membership

I have some users where the `IsApproved` column in the database is set to false. This means that they cant login.

What could be the reason that this happens, and how can I prevent `IsApproved` to be set to false automatically?

Comment: We are seeing this years later too. The IsApproved flag gets set to false for unknown reasons and forces ValidateUser to return false. We always set the IsApproved to true when the user is created, so there is no reason for it to ever change. Something else in the background in Membership is changing it, and we can't figure out what it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The IsApproved column is set to false by default.  There are different ways to change this 
default behaviour.   See this link http://forums.asp.net/t/1086175.aspx/1 for changing.

Comment: Do you know what triggers it to be set to true, if the default is false?

Comment: This is the default value in the database defined by the membership provider.  You can change the default value in the db design.  refer the link above for it

Answer (score 2):

The [MembershipUser.IsApproved](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membershipuser.isapproved.aspx) Property details will clear you doubt regarding this.

> Gets or sets whether the membership user can be authenticated. *As like some administrator is moderating the website and it is false if your account has not yet been approved by the site's administrator. If he/she approves then it will set to true.*

for more information, you should go through [Examining ASP.NET's Membership, Roles, and Profile - Part 4](https://web.archive.org/web/20211016204853/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/050306-1.aspx) By Scott Mitchell

You can approve user by code as:

```
Dim User As MembershipUser
User = Nothing
User = Membership.GetUser("MyUsername")
If (User Not Nothing)
then 
User.IsApproved = False 
End If
```

Ref:
[Make New User default to IsApproved = true](http://forums.asp.net/t/1086175.aspx/1)
[Error approving membership user](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-us/winforms/thread/BF99D550-6950-4E43-A252-ACD2C3C8C5F2)
[Unlocking and Approving User Accounts (C#)](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/security/admin/unlocking-and-approving-user-accounts-cs)

```
  protected void IsApproved_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         // Toggle the user's approved status
         string userName = Request.QueryString["user"];
         MembershipUser usr = Membership.GetUser(userName);
         usr.IsApproved = IsApproved.Checked;
         Membership.UpdateUser(usr);
         StatusMessage.Text = "The user's approved status has been updated.";
    }
```

Use MemberShip to manage this stuff. Hope this help..

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately it doesn't answer howcome the IsApproved column has been set to false automatically. I dont use any features where i have to approve the membership manually. Some users have IsApproved set to true, others false. I would like to know howcome some are false, and some are true, when i didnt set these values myself.

Comment: have you checked the specified reference link - Make New User default to IsApproved = true for your answer..